# Twilio Forward and Voicemail

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Can someone help me?

I used twimlbin to help me in creating the below:

I am trying to have my twilio number forward to 2 numbers.  1 of the numbers have a whispher which lets me know when I pick up the phone that it is a call coming from my twilio number.

If none of us pick up, the caller should go to the voicemail.

It works as is but there are 2 issues:

When it forwards to voicemail, there is a 3-5 second pause before the voicemail starts playing.  This happens only when I include the whisper twimlbin to the `<number>`.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number

Also if I do answer the call.  When I hang up with the caller, the caller is immediately transferred to the voicemail.  The call should just hang up not transfer to the voicemail.

Here is the code:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Response>
<Dial timeout="10" record="true">
    <Number>1111111111</Number>
    <Number url="http://twimlbin.com/c25c5906">2222222222</Number>
</Dial>
<Redirect>http://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=info%40test.com&amp;Message=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2Ftestvoicemail1.mp3&amp;     </Redirect>
</Response>`
```

Any help would be appreciated